# How to filter custom post type by multiple Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax, multi-taxonomy-query

On the project there is a filter:

[image]

It should filter the custom post ty recipes. Selected items are checkboxes. So, several values for filtering can be selected at any time. But in my case, filtering works only on one selected element. For example, I chose 'Lorem inpus1' the recipes were filtered by it. Now I choose any other element 'Lorem inpus3' for example and previous results removed.  Here is my code. I think the reason is in it, but I cannot solve this issue.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'vicso_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'vicso_filter_function');


function vicso_filter_function(){
   //I think problem is here all every time when I make a selection, the function takes a new value
   $products_filter = $_POST['products'];
   $types_food_filter = $_POST['types_food'];

   if( isset( $products_filter ) && !empty( $products_filter) ){
    $products_data = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'products',
        'terms' => $products_filter
    );

 } else{
    $products_filter = '';
 }

 if( isset(  $types_food_filter ) && !empty(  $types_food_filter ) ){
    $types_food_data = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'types_food',
        'terms' =>  $types_food_filter
    );
  } else{
    $types_food_filter = '';
  }

  $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        $products_data,
        $types_food_data
    )
  );

  $recipes = new WP_Query( $args );

}
```

I don’t think the reason could be the javascript code, but here is the code that I call the function above.

```
$('#recipes-filter').change(function(){

let filter = $('#recipes-filter');

jQuery.ajax({
    url:filter.attr('action'),
    data:filter.serialize(),
    type:filter.attr('method'),
    success:function(data){
        jQuery('#default-recipes-content').hide();
        jQuery('#response-recipes-content').html(data);
    }
});
return false;

});
```

Comment: Check if `$products_filter` and `$types_food_filter` are **arrays of numbers**. 
Also, you use `$products_data` and `$types_food_data` variables in `tax_query`, but
they can be uninitialized (it depends on the posted data).

Comment: @nmr I'm afraid I can't get it for what reason do I need to check if $products_filter and $types_food_filter are arrays of numbers?

Comment: You have not indicated in `'tax_query'` the field by which you are looking for terms, so the default is "term_id". If you select two options ("_Lorem inpus1_", "_Lorem inpus3_") then `$_POST['products']` should contain two numbers.  
`'tax_query' => array(  
   array( 'taxonomy' => 'products',   'terms' => [ lorem_inpus1_ID, lorem_inpus3_ID ] ),  
   $types_food_data
)`.

Comment: @nmr So for this purpose, I need to use foreach loop and create the array with the selected field. But I also need to detect what from inputs is selected.

Comment: Yes, if more than one item is selected in the "product" filter, then `$products_filter` should be an array. Same for "Types of food" and `$types_food_filter`.

Comment: @nmr Thanks, the issue is solved now!